# Calling a key of a json_decoded array return NULL

Tags: php, json, pdo

I am struggling to understand why certain cases that specific way to access the key in PDO works while when I tried myself, it didn't.

For example,

```
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE eq_question SET ". $user->field ."=? WHERE questID=?");
```

this PDO accessed an array's key (which was in a javascript object then posted and json_decoded in PHP) with `$user->field`, but when I tried to simulate the decoded array and use `var_dump ($user->field)`, I will receive `NULL`.

Can anyone tell me why is it happening?

In the example below, when I `var_dump ($user)`, I can see all the keys, but when I do `var_dump($user->field)`, I only receive `null`, therefore, cause the class's `updateValue` fail.

An example to see what I mean:

```
class User {

    private $dbh;

    public function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$db)  {   
        $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$db,$user,$pass);           }
public function updateValue($user){ 
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE eq_question SET ". $user->field ."=? WHERE questID=?");
$sth->execute(array($user->newvalue, $user->id));
}


$user = new stdClass;
echo " <br>|||SPACE||| BEFORE ASSIGN A OBJECT OT THE ARRAY-  ";
$userParams = array('id' => 1, 'field' => 'questTitle', 'newvalue' => "Baaaaa");
var_dump($userParams);
$user = json_encode(array("user"=>$userParams));
echo " <br>|||SPACE||| BEFORE DECODE-  ";
var_dump($user);
echo " <br>|||SPACE||| BEFORE DECODE of field-  ";
var_dump($user->field);
$user = json_decode($user);
echo " <br>|||SPACE||| AFTER DECODE-  ";
var_dump($user);
$userN=new User(...//info is hided by intention!); 
$dump=$userN->updateValue($user);
echo " <br>|||SPACE||| PRINT-----  ";
print($dump);
echo " <br>|||SPACE||| VAR_DUMP-----  ";
var_dump($dump);
```

Thank You

Comment: Unrelated: You're using PDO wrong. `$user->field` should be a placeholder, NOT directly inserted into the query string.

Comment: your updateValue() method doesn't return anything, so why should expect to get anything but null when you look for a return value that doesn't exist?

Comment: yes, but you're using json-encode(). once you encode a PHP data structure, it's no longer a data structure. It's a STRING, yet you keep trying to use that string as object.

Comment: Like I said. you encode to json, then use that json string as an object. `$foo = json_encode($bar); echo $foo->baz` will **NEVER** work, because php strings are not objects. so why are you round-tripping everything through json?

Comment: READ MY COMMENT! You can **NOT** use the json-encoded string as an object. It's **NOT** an object!

Comment: Plz bare with me :) and what you mean is that encoded json can never be used in an pdo statement? what about decoded array? because that was the way works in a tutorial. and it uses the format of $user->field. Btw, why this $user->filed works assume the array decoded? Thanks!